# Using kotlin constants in java switch expression

Tags: java, kotlin

I've been looking into Kotlin lang recently and its interop with java. I have following java code:

```
public void select(int code) {
    switch code {
        case Service.CONSTANT_ONE:
            break;
        case Service.CONSTANT_TWO:
             break;
        default:
             break;
    }
}
```

Where `Service.kt` written as follows:

```
class Service {
    companion object {
        val CONSTANT_ONE = 1
        val CONSTANT_TWO = 2
    }
}
```

Java compiler says that CONSTANT_ONE and CONSTANT_TWO must be constants, but I don't know, how I can make them more constant than they are now. So my question is: how to use constants from kotlin in java swicth statement?

I'm using jdk8 and kotlin M14.

Comment: I don't know about kotlin. But in java a switch case constant must be known at compile time. So a final/constant field that is assigned during compile time can not be used in a switch statement.

Comment: @Pinkie yeah, if I declared `CONSTANT_ONE` as `static final` somewhere in java code, I could use it in switch statement. However I don't know how could I write it in more strict way in Kotlin than it is now.

Comment: M14 changes state "Since M14 we need to prefix Kotlin constants with const to be able to use them in annotations and see as fields from Java"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

M14 changes state "Since M14 we need to prefix Kotlin constants with const to be able to use them in annotations and see as fields from Java"

```
class Service {
    companion object {
        const val CONSTANT_ONE = 1
        const val CONSTANT_TWO = 2
    }
}
```

IntelliJ still shows me an error in the Java case but it compiles and works.

Comment: Still seeing the error (Constant expression required) in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 / Kotlin 1.0.2-release-IJ145-10, but it does compile and work for me (odd!)

Comment: Looks like a fix is coming in Kotlin 1.0.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12026

Answer (score 0):

A even more simple solution would be:
to declare the constants in the 'Kotlin file' instead of 'Kotlin class', which is basically declaring the constants outside the class scope and **they can be referenced anywhere** with proper imports.

```
const val CONSTANT_ONE = 1
const val CONSTANT_TWO = 2

class Service {
}
```

Or if you want something that's similar to `private static final int CONSTANT_ONE = 1;`

You can declare the constants to be private in Kotlin file, and only classes within the same file have accesses to it.

```
private const val CONSTANT_ONE = 1
class A{
   // can access CONSTANT_ONE
}

class B{
  // can access CONSTANT_ONE
}
```